# Polkadot Election Failure

Tags: polkadot, election, npos

I created a Polkadot private chain with 5 validator candidates and 4 validator active. If I set 1 epoch = 1 era and shutdown one active validator, there is no problem, the standby validator takes over and the chain continues. However, if I set 6 epoch = 1 era and shutdown 1 active validator, the election will fail and will need to go execute governance fallback to bring it again to normal. Why is this happening?

Comment: update: calling forceNewEraAlways() also works since this will make 1 era = 1 epoch. what i don't understand is why elections will fail if there are multiple epochs for each era.